# Draw a "L" using the DrawingContext

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, drawing

I need to Draw (using `System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext`) a "`L`" in WPF. 
What is the optimal way to proceed?

Draw 2 lines? Draw a `PolyLineSegment`? (not sure how)

```
drawContext.DrawLine(myPen, topLeft, New Point(topLeft.X + 5, topLeft.Y))
drawContext.DrawLine(myPen, topLeft, New Point(topLeft.X, topLeft.Y + 5))
```

Actually, I need to surround a label with visible corners "L"-like...
I need to *draw*, **not** to use Templates or Decorators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your question is about adding as few as possible `Drawing` objects to your `DrawingContext`, you might populate a [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx) and draw it by [DrawGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawgeometry.aspx).